# Why in this exercise in my function deleteTodo the toggle method doesn't work when I click in the check mark button?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, conditional-statements, toggle

I am a very beginner coder and I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ttf3CEsEwMQ&t=914s to do a vanilla to-do list, I was ok until the 38 minute of the video, I don't know why in my function **deleteTodo**, the  **todo.classList.toggle("completed")**;is not working!! I've checked almost all morning what cold be wrong and I can't figure it out, I really need help to move forward, I changed almost everything in the code to see if the name of the class was the problem if I had a typo problem but nothing. I really think the problem is with the toggle method because when I checked that with remove() it works so I think is something related with method.

I really appreciate a hand here!
This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/be9d53aead.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>To-do-list</title>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="main-square"> 
        <header>
    <h1> My week plan</h1>
    <h2> Organize your life with this lovely planner</h2>
    </header>
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the work" class="todo-input" />
        <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
    <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
        </button> 
        
        <div class="todo-container">
            <ul class="todo-list"> </ul>

      </div>
            
    </div>
   
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </html>
```

```
body{
    background-color: pink;
    color: #337676;
  
}

/* big screen */
.main-square{
    background-color: #9fd3c7;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 650px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

h1{
    font-size: 44px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input[type="text"]{
    width: 400px;
    padding: 13px 13px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
}


.todo-button{
    padding: 13px 13px;
    margin-left: -11px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: none;
    background: white;
    color: #9fd3c7;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


.todo-button:hover{
    background: #9fd3c7;
    color: white;
}


.todo-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.todo-list{
    min-width: 30%;
    list-style: none;
}

.todo{
    margin: 0.5rem;
    background: white;
    color: #337676;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.todo li {
    flex: 1;
}

.trash-btn, .complete-btn{
    background: pink;
    color: #337676;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.trash-btn:hover{
   background: rgb(136, 20, 84);
   color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.complete-btn:hover{
   background: #9fd3c7;
   color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.fa-trash,
.fa-check {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.completed{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```
   //Selectors
   const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
   const todoButton = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
   const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");

   //Event listeners
   todoButton.addEventListener("click", addTodo);
   todoList.addEventListener("click", deleteTodo);
   //Functions

   function addTodo(event){
    //Prevent form from submitting
   event.preventDefault();
   //Todo DIV
   const todoDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
   todoDiv.classList.add("todo");
   //Create li
   const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
   newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
   newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
   todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
   //Check mark button
   const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
   completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class= "fas fa-check"> </i>'
   completedButton.classList.add("complete-btn");
   todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
    //Check trash button
   const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
   trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class= "fas fa-trash"> </i>'
   trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
   todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
   //Append to list
   todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
   //Clear todo INPUT VALUE
   todoInput.value = "";
   }

    function deleteTodo(e){
    const item = e.target;
    if (item.classList[0] === 'trash-btn'){
        const todo = item.parentElement; 
        todo.remove();
    }
    if (item.classList[0] === "complete-btn") {
    const todo = item.parentElement;
    todo.classList.toggle("completed");
    }
    }
```

I tried changing this line:    todo.classList.toggle("completed") for todo.toggle("completed"), also todo.classList.toggle("complete-btn") also todo.classList.toggle(completedButton)

```
function deleteTodo(e){
const item = e.target;
if (item.classList[0] === 'trash-btn'){
    const todo = item.parentElement; 
    todo.remove();
}
if (item.classList[0] === "complete-btn") {
const todo = item.parentElement;
todo.classList.toggle("completed");
}
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and it is working. The delete button definitely works as intended at least.

Comment: Yes it works but when I click the check mark button doesn't do the toggle function properly :(

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your "deleteTodo" function functions properly, it is necessary to add e.preventDefault() to it. This addition prevents the default behavior from occurring, giving your function the ability to handle the event in a personalized way without causing the page to refresh. Here is what your updated "deleteTodo" function code should look like:

```
function deleteTodo(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const item = e.target;
  if (item.classList[0] === "trash-btn") {
      const todo = item.parentElement;
      todo.remove();
  }
  if (item.classList[0] === "complete-btn") {
      const todo = item.parentElement;
      todo.classList.toggle("completed");
  }
}
```

Comment: You are a legend!! I can't believe I didn't notice that, thanks 1000!